# Ajax: GET call to api on Cross subdomain

Tags: ajax, .htaccess

I am trying to make ajax call to my crm api using this code but cant get this work without errors:

```
var username = 'admin';
var password = '1';

$.ajax
({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false,
  url: "http://demo.espocrm.com/basic/api/v1/App/user",
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)
  }
})
.done(function(){
    alert('Authenticated!')
})
.fail(function(){
    alert('Error!')
});
```

the call come from `www.domain.com` to `crm.domain.com`

in the `.htaccess` on `crm.domain.com` i have this code:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://www.domain.com"
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "OPTIONS, GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD"
   Header set Access-Control-Max-Age "1800"
</ifModule>
```

- I also tried to use `jsnot` and use this url: `http://demo.espocrm.com/basic/api/v1/App/user?callback=?`

the errors are:

```
OPTIONS http://crm.domain.com/api/v1/App/user?_=1437237158381 500 (Internal Server Error)


XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://crm.domain.com/api/v1/App/user?_=1437237158381. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.domain.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

when i use `jsnop`:

```
GET http://crm.domain.com/api/v1/App/user?callback=jQuery21404605716757941991_1437238651212&_=1437238651213
```

Comment: And which are the errors you get? Or do you want us to _guess_?

Comment: @arkascha sorry forgot to mention. i have update my question

Comment: HTTP code 500 is a server internal error. That would mean that the request does work, but your crm server fails to process it. I suggest you take a look into its error log file.